# Ajax.BeginForm returns full page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I want to use the Ajax.BeginForm, without updating any element, only call the callback javascript function.

I've attached js libraries

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I use:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions {OnComplete = "AddPostComplete"}))
{
//some code
}
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#asdf').click(function () {
        //some code
    });
</script>
```

the js function isn't used, and the page return full view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With unobtrusive javascript enabled you will also need to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`